# How to format 2016-02-12T15:23:20+02:00 time

Tags: java, android, date

I'm getting the above Date format from our webservice. I have an idea on how to format the date, im just having issues with the fact it comes down as a string.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119072/android-java-convert-string-date-to-long-type) but I need to return it as a String, which in a way isn't a problem.

This is what I have tried but it throws an Exception:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:
>   "2016-02-26T00:00:00+02:00" (at offset 4)

Code:

```
  public static String formatDate(String unFormattedTime) {
    String formattedTime;
    try {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM HH:mm");
      Date date = sdf.parse(unFormattedTime);

      formattedTime = sdf.format(date);
      return formattedTime;

    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";
  }
```

How could I format it in a format like dd MMM HH:mm?

Comment: If you want a string, then use a new SimpleDateFormat class to reformat the timestamp. Don't use the getTime method to get the long. That link you posted tells you how to parse one string into a date object

Comment: And you need to get the correct formatting to avoid your current error.

Comment: you could substitude your ":" and "+" before you format your String. Also why do you get a String representation from your webService cant you grab the calendar or date Object itself?

Comment: Just use *DateFormat DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM HH:mm");*

Comment: Maybe you should deal with the String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are with a working snippet of what you want to achieve:

```
public class FormatDateExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String date =  "2016-02-26T00:00:00+02:00";
        System.out.println(formatDate(date));

    }

    public static String formatDate(String unFormattedTime) {
         String formattedTime;
         try {
             SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
             Date date = sdf.parse(unFormattedTime);

             sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM HH:mm");
             formattedTime = sdf.format(date);

             return formattedTime;

        } catch (ParseException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

First you have to parse the date with the given format you have

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse(unFormattedTime);
```

Then you have to format that date to the desired format "dd MMM HH:mm"

```
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM HH:mm");
formattedTime = sdf.format(date);
```

Comment: That worked like a charm!!! it seems i just had it the wrong way around, formatting then parsing. thanks a mill

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8 you can try this:

LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(unFormattedTime, ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)

Ref:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME