# Getting crash while converting date format

Tags: android, date, calendar

I getting a crash while getting this date format from server side and then i have been analyzed in google but didn't get any right solution for this.How to convert this date format to this way attached below
Crash occurred in **"startDate":"2018-01-23T00:00:00.000-05:00"** this date

Expected date format:**"2018-01-24 00:43:10 -0500"**
Suggest some possible solutions.

```
 SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
    inFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    String date = null;
    try {
        Date toConvert = inFormat.parse(OurDate);
        date = inFormat.format(toConvert);
    } catch (ParseException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date.toString();
}
```

Comment: i think that `T` is the issue.

Comment: yea....thats issue...how to remove the T?

Comment: u should see here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597083/illegal-pattern-character-t-when-parsing-a-date-string-to-java-util-date

Comment: @MaheskumarSubramani you can change your Input formate check below my answer.

Comment: use **"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"** as `inFormat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");

SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat output1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");

Date d = null;
try 
{
      d = input.parse("2018-01-23T00:00:00.000-05:00");

} 
catch (ParseException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String formatted = output.format(d);
Log.i("DATE", "" + formatted);

String formatted1 = output1.format(d);
Log.i("DATE1", "" + formatted1);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
I/DATE: 23/01/2018

I/DATE1: 2018-01-23 00:00:00 +0530
```

Comment: @Maheskumar Subramani if you solve your problem. please select answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are with a working snippet of what you want to achieve:

```
public class FormatDateExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String date =  "2016-02-26T00:00:00+02:00";
        System.out.println(formatDate(date));

    }

    public static String formatDate(String unFormattedTime) {
         String formattedTime;
         try {
             SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
             Date date = sdf.parse(unFormattedTime);

             sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM HH:mm");
             formattedTime = sdf.format(date);

             return formattedTime;

        } catch (ParseException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

First you have to parse the date with the given format you have

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse(unFormattedTime);
```

Then you have to format that date to the desired format "dd MMM HH:mm"

```
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM HH:mm");
formattedTime = sdf.format(date);
```

Source.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35500350/3790052