# Current best practice for timed job execution in Android

Tags: android, time, alarmmanager

Since I'm struggling a lot with the Android Oreo background restriction, I was asking myself if working with the `AlarmManager` is even the best way of timing Job execution to e.g. 03:00 AM. I saw some people use `JobScheduler`, but it seems it's not that suitable for executing tasks every day at a given time.

I was trying just `AlarmManager` with a `BroadcastReceiver`, then inserted the `BroadcastReceiver` in a (in theory) self-starting service, but since an app isn't able to call `startService()` when in background this also doesn't work the way it should (and also seems kinda wrong).

Am I missing something? What's the current way to go?
Obviously there are ways, because otherwise Messengers, Games and other Apps won't be able to work the way they do.

```
public class BackgroundTaskWorker extends Worker {

    public BackgroundTaskWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Log.i("WORKING","DOING SOME WORK");
        Context con = getApplicationContext();
        SharedPreferences preferences = con.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.sharedPrefs, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editPrefs = preferences.edit();
        int day = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        String s_day = preferences.getString("DAY","0");
        int old_day = Integer.parseInt(s_day);
        if(old_day == 0){
            Log.i("WORKING","old_day default");
            editPrefs.putString("DAY",Integer.toString(day));
            editPrefs.commit();
            return Result.success();
        }
        else if(day == old_day) {
            Log.i("WORKING", "day=old_day default");
            return Result.success();
        }
        else {
            Log.i("WORKING","old_day change");
            editPrefs.putString("DAY",Integer.toString(day));
            editPrefs.commit();
            Log.d("BISASAM","triggered");


            DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.GERMANY);
            Date dat = new Date();
            Log.d("TRIGGERDATE",date.format(dat));
            editPrefs.putString("REC", "Receiver called "+date.format(dat));


            NotificationCompat.Builder builder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(con,"ID");
            builder.setContentTitle("ALARM FIRED");
            builder.setContentText("WORKER");
            builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.kreuz);
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                Log.d("BUILDCHECK","correct");
                CharSequence name = "NotChannel";
                String desc = "Test Channel for Planer";
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("NOT",name,importance);
                channel.setDescription(desc);
                NotificationManager notManager = con.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                notManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(con);
                builder.setChannelId("NOT");
                notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());
            }
            //TODO Test Tageswechsel Wiederholende Tasks
            String today = preferences.getString("0",null);
            String tomorrow = preferences.getString("1",null);
            String next_week = preferences.getString("7",null);
            String next_month = preferences.getString("30",null);
            if(today != null) {
                String[] repetitive = today.split(" ");
                for (int j = 1; j < repetitive.length; j += 2) {
                    Log.d("PIKACHU",repetitive[j-1]);
                    switch(repetitive[j]){
                        case "1":
                            if(tomorrow!=null)
                                tomorrow += ","+ repetitive[j-1]+" "+repetitive[j];
                            else
                                tomorrow=repetitive[j-1]+" "+repetitive[j];
                            break;
                        case "7":
                            if(next_week!=null)
                                next_week += ","+ repetitive[j-1]+" "+repetitive[j];
                            else
                                next_week=repetitive[j-1]+" "+repetitive[j];
                            break;
                        case "30":
                            if(next_month!=null)
                                next_month += ","+ repetitive[j-1]+" "+repetitive[j];
                            else
                                next_month=repetitive[j-1]+" "+repetitive[j];
                            break;
                        default:
                    }

                }
            }
            Log.d("PUTTING",tomorrow);
            Log.d("PUTTING",next_week);
            Log.d("PUTTING",next_month);
            editPrefs.putString("1",tomorrow);
            editPrefs.putString("7",next_week);
            editPrefs.putString("30",next_month);
            editPrefs.commit();
            ArrayList<String> month = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < Jobs.month_length; i++) {
                month.add(preferences.getString(Integer.toString(i),""));
            }
            for (int i=1;i<Jobs.month_length;i++){
                month.set(i-1,month.get(i));
            }
            month.set(30,"");
            for(int i=0;i<Jobs.month_length;i++){
                editPrefs.putString(Integer.toString(i),month.get(i));
            }
            Log.d("COMMITED",month.toString());
            editPrefs.commit();
        }
        // Indicate success or failure with your return value:
        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

```
 private void registerWorker(){
        unregisterWorker();
        PeriodicWorkRequest request= new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(BackgroundTaskWorker.class,
                20, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .addTag("AUFGABEN_PLANER_BACK")
                .build();
        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("AUFGABEN_PLANER_BACK", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, request);
    }
    private void unregisterWorker(){
        WorkManager.getInstance().cancelAllWorkByTag("AUFGABEN_PLANER_BACK");
    }
```

registerWorker is called everytime MainActivity gets started (=> at the app start)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279364/android-workmanager-vs-jobscheduler

Comment: Is this possible with WorkManager? Setting a task to execute always at a given time? And is this "backgroundsafe" for Android Oreo and above?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: yes it will work dear

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363541/schedule-a-work-on-a-specific-time-with-workmanager As of here it doesn't seem to be possible to run it at a specific time

Comment: So it seems the problem is related to power saving mode, because when i deactivated it it worked fine. But how do apps like e.g. WhatsApp or Clash of Clans still send notifications when the power saving mode is on ( not the maximum one ofc)

Comment: most of the customized os provides access to those big apps already like autorun etc and in stock there is not much features given which like battery saving, autorun app etc

Comment: did my answer work for you  ?

Comment: So I just have to realize it doesn't work in any way when the device is in power saving mode ?

Comment: probably yes , might depends on OS also Customize OS has more limitiations

Comment: you should create issue in google developers community , mention everything

Answer (score 1):

Use **WorkManager** for Scheduling task in `background` and `foreground`

Example for **Periodic Request**

```
PeriodicWorkRequest request= new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(WorkerClass.class,
                            24, TimeUnit.HOURS).setInitialDelay(THE_DELAY,TimeUnit.SECONDS).addTag("TAG").build()
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("TAG", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, request);
```

Create a worker class

```
public class WorkerClass extends Worker {
    @Override
    public Worker.WorkerResult doWork() {

        // Do the work here

        // Indicate success or failure with your return value:
        return WorkerResult.SUCCESS;

        // (Returning RETRY tells WorkManager to try this task again
        // later; FAILURE says not to try again.)
    }
}
```

Now call this class by

Example for One Time request

```
OneTimeWorkRequest request= new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(WorkerClass .class)
.setInitialDelay(delayedTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.addTag("TAG")
.build();
 WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("TAG", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, request);
```

where `delayedTime` is calculated time to do task

add this in **build.gradle**

```
 implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:2.1.0-alpha02'
```

check the latest release doc
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work

also you can convert your time
[Android / Java convert String date to long type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119072/android-java-convert-string-date-to-long-type)

Comment: and for reocurring tasks? how would that be implemented?

Comment: check my answer now

Comment: So I gotta calculate the offset once, and then the work will always be done at the time = current_time + offset?

Comment: THE_DELAY = currentTime (in Millis) - specificTimeToTrigger (in Millis)

Comment: Thank you I will try that, but one last thing. The line for build.gradle can't be resolved. Any ideas why?

Comment: use androidx version , i also updated the answer please check

Comment: btw there is no such function as setInitialDelay(). The only ones I see is setPeriodStartTime or setScheduleRequestedAt(). Both of them can't be called btw because of "not in same library group"

Comment: you have to use 2.1.0a  alpha release to use that method
API Changes

PeriodicWorkRequests now support initial delays. You can use the setInitialDelay method on PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder to set an initial delay

Comment: But (At least) in the emulator it doesn't seem to work when the device is in standby. Any way to make sure it still works, when the device is in standby?

Comment: wait let me check . but please check it in a real device and let me know the behaviour

Comment: So it seems like the worker gets called but only executed when I open the app. I need it do to work when the app is closed.

Comment: which device are you testing with ? and post your code here

Comment: Im testing with a Samsung Galaxy S8 with Android 9.0 installed. Do you need the whole code? Or just the one related to the WorkManager

Comment: okay i will check and post the appropriate code related to it please